# 2d array indexing fails for static arrays

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

I have a basic question related to indexing 2d arrays passed to a function in C. When I use a double pointer to pass it:

- Inside the function `printMatrix` indexing `A` as `A[i][j]` works if memory for `A` in `main` was allocated using `malloc`
- Inside the function `printMatrix` indexing `A` as `A[i][j]` doesn't work if memory for `A` in `main` was allocated statically (as in the commented code). I believe I should use: `*(*(A+i*N)+j)` but why doesn't `A[i][j]` work when it works for the case above?

---

```
void printMatrix(int** A,int N) {
    int i=0,j=0;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<N;j++) {
            printf("%2d",A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return;
}

int main() {
    //int A[6][6] = {{1,1,1,1,1,1},{2,2,2,2,2,2},{3,3,3,3,3,3},
    //{4,4,4,4,4,4},{5,5,5,5,5,5},{6,6,6,6,6,6}};
    int N = 6,i,j;
    int **A = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*N);
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        A[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*N);

    for(i=0;i<N;i++) 
        for(j=0;j<N;j++)
            A[i][j] = i+j;

    printMatrix((int**)A,N);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you have `int A[6][6]`, then passing it to a function does not give you an `int **` argument.  You have a true array, not an array of pointers to arrays of `int`.  The compiler told you about it; that's presumably why you have the bludgeon `(int **)A` cast in the call to `printMatrix()`.  The cast says "I know better than the compiler"; that's not a good idea when you don't.

Answer (score 1):

Taking an analytical viewpoint, if we declare an array with automatic storage duration in main, such as:

```
int A[6][6];
```

We can measure the size of this allocation by using `sizeof A`, and this will be equal to `sizeof (int) * 6 * 6`.

In the following code, however, you are allocating `sizeof (int *) * 6 + sizeof (int) * 6 * 6` bytes:

```
int N = 6,i,j;
int **A = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*N);
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    A[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*N);
```

This should indicate a flaw in your understanding of arrays, and **you're doing too much work**. For a start, an array is a single continuous block of memory, while what you're allocating is not. You're calling `malloc` too many times, and allocating too many bytes.

If you continue to *sharpen your axe* by learning more about C, you'll learn neat tricks such as achieving your goal with one allocation, allocating the same number of bytes, and with one line of code:

```
int (*A)[N] = malloc(N * sizeof *A);
```

You'll probably want to adjust the type of `print_matrix` to reflect the change of `A` as follows:

```
void printMatrix(size_t N, int (*A)[N])
```

P.S. [Don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

P.P.S. Check `malloc` for `NULL` return values.

P.P.P.S. There are two meanings for "static" in C, and neither of them are what you think they are...

Comment: :) Thank you Seb. I love your P.S's. Can you explain a bit more on what int (*A)[N] = malloc(N * sizeof *A); does? What can such arrays be called - statically initialized or compile-time available arrays?

Comment: Can you also answer as to why (a) works and (b) doesn't?

Comment: @Vandana I mostly have, by writing "an array is a single continuous block of memory, while what you're allocating is not".

Comment: @Vandana You need to realise why your compiler is warning you when you remove the cast from `printMatrix((int**)A,N);`... It's because the underlying allocations are different, and the type reflects that the underlying allocations are different. Different type, different representation, and you get a warning.

Comment: For sure, I could write an entire chapter of a book on the types in C and how and when they convert... but that is something your book should cover. If you have to ask for further details on this, it's probably because your book isn't working for you.